# How to close notifications with the keyboard?

Tags: gnome, notification

my problem is that when I insert a drive (HDD partition, DVD etc.) a notification appears, which has a unlimited duration.

Clicking somewhere (except the options) will close this notification, but it is bothersome 
that I always have to use the mouse.

Is there a way to close these notifications with the keyboard or to set a duration?

Comment: When I mount a volume, I want nautilus to open it, which works by default. But these notifications still appear. I don't really mind them, but I'd like to be able to close them via keyboard. When inserting a DVD or something like that it is okay for them to appear, but when I just mount them the notifications are useless... So I'd at least like to also be able to close these notifications with the keyboard and not only with the mouse...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an answer to closing it with the keyboard but if you edit the /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/autorunManager.js and change the line

```
this.setUrgency(MessageTray.Urgency.CRITICAL);
```

to

```
this.setUrgency(MessageTray.Urgency.NORMAL);
```

It will only pop up for a few seconds and then disappear.  You will still have the Icon in the panel, it will just not bug you down below.

Answer (score 0):

Use Esc Key. It works for most of the pop-up dialogues:)

Comment: This isn't a dialog though, and Escape doesn't make it go away